# Eclipse cannot build, but maven can since moving from Java 8 to Java 11

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, module, eclipse-2019-03

Here is the minimal [reproduction](https://github.com/electroCutie/EclipseBug_Java11)

I'm using Eclipse `Version: 2019-03 M1 (4.11.0 M1)`, `Build id: 20190117-2133`

The jars in question are Selenium, but they are the only ones in the main project which are multi-release jars, so I think that may be part of the problem

Basically, Eclipse has an error on build

```
selenium.firefox.driver cannot be resolved to a module
```

and all imports of the classes under that module give the error

```
The import org.openqa.selenium cannot be resolved
```

Or some variation thereof. Sometimes it is `org` that it claims to not be able to resolve

Importantly, this *does* successfully compile under Maven

Comment: By the looks of it Java 11 does not support Selenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Selenium with Java 11. Just can remove Selenium from your module_info.java and use it as an additional jar file.

If you want to use Selenium as a Java module, you have to edit your project setup and add Selenium to your Modulepath like that:

[image: Eclipse Modulepath setup]

Unfortunately the Maven plugin seems to ignore this during an Eclipse project update (not only with Selenium).

To get this fixed, I had to modify the module-info.java as well:

```
module browserAutomation{

  requires org.openqa.selenium.core;
  requires org.openqa.selenium.firefox;

}
```

This is corresponding to the source code at https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium

Comment: It is in 3.141.59, that is it is a multi version jar with a version 9 config. Also, again, this properly builds in maven just not eclipse

Comment: I'll give it a shot as soon as I can, and hopefully this will do the trick. Thanks!